# after uploading excel the cell value differs in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

After uploading `my.df` as `my.df <- read_excel("C:/mydirectory.xlsx", sheet = "my.sheet")` the first value of the cell becomes `"1.1000000000000001"` rather than `1.1` why would that be the case? many thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558

Comment: You can use the format function to round the numeric column to a specific number of decimal places. For example:
{my.df$column_name <- format(my.df$column_name, nsmall = 1)}